# Checkbox turns into text input ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, checkbox, asp.net-core

I was attempting to make two checkboxes on an ASP.NET Core cshtml page like this:

```
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input asp-for="IsDesktop" />
        <label asp-for="IsDesktop">Desktop page</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <input asp-for="IsPhone" />
        <label asp-for="IsPhone">Phone page</label>
    </div>
```

This code yields two different results!
[One type="text", and one type="checkbox" (see picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp65N.png)

Both database columns are of type "bit" (either 1 or 0 for true or false).

What makes one of these inputs turn out as a text input?

Comment: you speak of database columns which is irrelevant, you should show your model and what type those properties have on your model. most likely one of those is an int instead of bool so it gets text instead of checkbox

Comment: Interesting. My model was created automatically from a pre-existing database via scaffolding, so I do believe that the database types are significant.
Good hint, though. The difference in the auto-generated model was "bool?" versus "bool"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: From Joe Audette's comment, I found that the model showed one datatype as "bool?" and another as "bool".

In order to make these both into checkboxes, I had to make the columns in the database nullable and regenerate my models, in order to make them "bool?".

Answer (score 0):

The asp-for attribute relates the tag to the model, which helps asp.net infer the html input type to use.

http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/13/mvc6-input-tag-helper-deep-dive.aspx